# jQuery validator to show relevant download link

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, password-protection

I'm using the validator plugin to add various password fields to a site, each one releasing a relevant download link upon the successful password being entered. The problem is, when the correct password is being entered, ALL the download links are being shown and not just the relevant one. All the fields will have the same password, and more files will be added over time, I'm just trying to figure out how to ONLY show the relevant download link instead of all of them.
Here's a jsfiddle (the password is 'password'): http://jsfiddle.net/rqGWK/ 
jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".article-form").hide();
jQuery(".download-file").hide();

jQuery('.article-link').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.article-form').fadeIn();
    });


    jQuery.validator.addMethod("pw_check", function (value) {
        return (value == 'password');
    }, "Invalid password");


    jQuery(".article-form").validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                pw_check: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            jQuery(".article-form").hide();
            jQuery(".download-file").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: You need to give the relevant `.download-file` and ID and the show that instead of running fade in on all `.download-file` items.  Also, `.hide()` isn't really 'protecting' anything. It's just hiding it from display.  I wouldn't recommend this unless you aren't truly worried about security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using jQuery or any client side code as a tool to protect content. It's not true security.

But to answer your question..just look for `.download-file` in the `.parent()` and wrap your `.validate()` function so each form is validated.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcjqj/1/)** Updated.

```
jQuery('.article-link').click(function () {
    if(jQuery(this).siblings('.download-file').css('display')=='none')
       jQuery(this).siblings('.article-form').fadeIn();
});

jQuery(".article-form").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                pw_check: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            jQuery(form).hide();
            jQuery(form).siblings(".download-file").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Little bug: if the link is already unlocked the form reappears equally

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[DEMO VIEW](http://jsfiddle.net/rqGWK/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery(".article-form").hide();
 jQuery(".download-file").hide();

var actual;
var validates = [];

 jQuery('.article-link').click(function() {
    actual = $(this).closest('.article-download');
if(!validates[actual.index()]){
    $(".article-form").hide()
    $(".article-form").eq(actual.index()).fadeIn();
}
});


jQuery.validator.addMethod("pw_check", function (value) {
    return (value == 'password');
}, "Invalid password");


jQuery(".article-form").validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            pw_check: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        validates[actual.index()] = true;
        jQuery(".article-form").hide();
        jQuery(".download-file").eq(actual.index()).fadeIn("slow");
    }
 }); 

});
```

PS: The client side is bypassable, remember of do server-side control